# I want to return only and integer from an Android Database

Tags: android, database

I have already built a working database and want to return the `max(_id)` . I do not want a cursor though, I know it is going to be and `int` I only want to return the number. Is there a way to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [simpleQueryForLong](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#simpleQueryForLong%28%29) is what you are looking for.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
// initialize the db
SQLiteStatement statement = null;
try {
    db.compileStatement("select max(_id) from table");
    int max = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle
} finally {
    if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```